# php sql multiple search

Tags: php, sql, search

I want to write a php code that can search for multiple keywords separated by a column. Currently my code is working accurately for a particular single keyword. 
Also; what changes should i make in the SQL table?

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if($_POST)
{
$q=$_POST['searchword'];
$sql_res = mysql_query("SELECT tag_id, tag_name FROM ttl_tags WHERE tag_name like '%$q%' ORDER BY tag_id LIMIT 5");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_res))
{
$tagid=$row['tag_id'];
$tagname=$row['tag_name'];
$re_tagname='<b>'.$q.'</b>';
$final_tagname = str_ireplace($q, $re_tagname, $tagname);

?>
```

Comment: how many keywords at maximum would you search for?

Comment: and what is the expected max size of ttl_tags? In number of different tags OR number of total rows? (more or less...)

Comment: max. size of ttl_tags will be three.
ttl_id is an id given to ttl_tags..
eg: "1";"blue"==> ttl_id=1 & ttl_tags=blue.
The user will search for key-words aka ttl_tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading your question right, you want to search for multiple keywords in a single column? If so you can do:

```
 $sql_res = mysql_query("SELECT tag_id, tag_name FROM ttl_tags 
            WHERE tag_name like '%$q%' OR tag_name like 'ANOTHER_PARAMETER'  
            ORDER BY tag_id LIMIT 5");
```

You can put as many "OR"s that you want.